# How to increase rotate value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## The Problem

I want to increase the rotate value to a `div` by using jquery, i know you can increase the value of `height` and `width` by `$("#div").css('height','+=200px')` but you cant do that with `transform` property because it got many value like translate, rotate, scale, and skew.

## Question

How to increase rotate value `transform: rotate(30deg);` by `30deg` to become `60deg` ?

i dont want to do `transform: rotate(60deg);` with css or`$("#mydiv").css('transform','rotate(60deg)')` with Jquery.

## Code

```js
// Any idea ?
```

```css
#container{
  padding: 100px;
}
#mydiv{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: pink;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

#### Hint

I tried `$("#mydiv").css('transform')` it return matrix value.

Comment: you say "How to increase rotate value transform" but "i dont want to do with css" or "with Jquery" - how then you want to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain why `i dont want to do transform: rotate(60deg); with css or$("#mydiv").css('transform','rotate(60deg)') with Jquery.`? They are by far the best, and most appropriate solutions here. It's like saying 'I want to tie my shoelaces, but I don't want to use my hands'

Comment: first i want to **get** the current value of `transform: rotate` then add to this value `30deg` ?

Comment: here is a snippet to parse the rotation matrix - https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

the `getRotationDegrees()` function will calculate the rotate degress and return the value.

```js
function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
    var matrix = obj.css("transform");
    if(matrix !== 'none') {
        var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
        var a = values[0];
        var b = values[1];
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
    } else { var angle = 0; }
    return (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;
}


var rotate = getRotationDegrees($("#mydiv")) + 30;
$('#mydiv').css('transform', 'rotate('+rotate+'deg)')
```

```css
#container{
  padding: 100px;
}
#mydiv{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: pink;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by adding `rotate` into your `css('transform'` call:

```
var value = 60;
$("#mydiv").css('transform', 'rotate(' + value + 'deg)');
```

More [demos with CSS3 transitions using jQuery here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css3-transitions-and-jquery.shtml)

Comment: read the question again please :) ( i dont want to do `$("#mydiv").css('transform','rotate(60deg)') `with Jquery ) ` )

Comment: what exactly it returns ?

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: oops ... I just saw that you don't want to use css, but I will leave answer here for reference*

isn't this the purpose of *transition*?

```
.my_div_class__closed
  { transform  : rotate(30deg)    ;
    transition : transform 200   ;
    /*                 You could substitute 200 (as in milliseconds) to 0     
                       if you want instantaneous change. 
    */
  }
.my_div_class__opened
  { transform  : rotate(60deg)    ;
  }
```

***NOTE***: vendor prefixes not used in example ... if you don't know vendor prefixes, then copy/paste css snippet into service like [autoprefixer](http://autoprefixer.github.io/) .. and be sure to use filter value: `>0%`